# elasticsearch query not returning anything despite data existing

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to send a query and get the result from an elastic search index. When i do the searching from kibana i get a result but when i do it from an api endpoint the result body is undefined.

```
app.get('/yayin/ara', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { q } = req.query;

// Make a search query
const { body } = await esClient.search({
  index: "yayinlar",
 body:{
    query: {
      match: {
        title: q,
      },
    },
  },
});
console.log(q);
console.log(body);
if (!body) {
  return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Invalid Elasticsearch response format.' });
}

// Check if the 'hits' property exists in the response
const hits = body.hits?.hits?.map(hit => hit._source) || [];

// Extract and send the search results as a response
res.json({ results: hits });
  } catch (error) {
   console.error('Error searching in Elasticsearch:', error);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
}
})
```

In here `console.log(q)` does print the query value but the result body is printing "undefined"